# Backbone.js - Temporarily disabling (events in) View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

**TL;DR** How to temporarily disable a View so I can safely load another View, then safely close the loaded View to return to the original View?

I have the following scenario:

1. User opens `/search` which loads `SearchView`.
2. User clicks a button to perform search.
3. Collection inside `SearchView` is filled with data, UI is updated to reflect that.
4. User clicks a result item.
5. `SearchView` is disabled (only need to disable `events`?).
6. `ItemView` is loaded, displaying the item detail.
7. User clicks a button to close `ItemView`.
8. `SearchView` is re-enabled.

What is the best way to achieve point 5 and 8? I'm thinking of calling `SearchView.unbind()` (for point 5) and `SearchView.bind()` (for point 8).

**Bonus**: It would be better if the solution is stack-like. I.e. View A loads View B which can load View C. When View C is closed, View B is reinstated, etc.

Comment: why don't you use `router.navigate` to move the user into `ItemView` with the data they've selected and unload the `SearchView`.  This would make it so you don't have to unbind anything.

Comment: This would also give the added benefit that the user can click back to go back to search results from the item details

Comment: @tkone I use `router.navigate` to update URL but can't destroy `SearchView` as the search result is displayed using infinite scrolling. Scroll position must be maintained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calling `SearchView.undelegateEvents()` for point 5, and then `SearchView.delegateEvents()` for point 8.